# Some things about structures in C - which I dont understand

Tags: c, structure

I know that we can assign one structure to another, but we can't assign element of one structure to another.

```
struct Date {
    int sec;
    int min;
    int hour;
};

struct Date d1={1,2,3};
struct Date d2={10,20,4};
```

So I know it is valid:

```
d1=d2;
```

But it is not (because we can't assign elements of struct)

```
d1.sec=d2.sec
```

But now I am wondering, what if elements of one structure is another structure, like this:

```
struct DateTime {
struct Date d;
struct Time t;
};

struct DateTime dt1;
struct DateTime dt2;
```

So if we do this:

```
dt1=dt2;
```

are we assigning structures(Date and Time) from dt2 to structures(Date and Time) to dt1?

Also now (when elements of one structure is another structures) can we assign elements, like this:

```
dt1.d = dt2.d
```

Comment: `d1.sec=d2.sec` is perfectly fine

Comment: `dt1.d = dt2.d` is perfectly fine, but if you are working with `struct` pointers you will need for example `pt1->d = pt2->d;`

Comment: Why do you think you can't do `d1.sec=d2.sec`?

Comment: because professor told about d1.string = d2.string (you cant assign strings(char array)) in c, so I connected that with int. My mistake

Comment: I've edited the code in your question. It had syntax errors, and the indentation was misleading. Any code in a question should be copy-and-pasted from code that you've actually compiled. This ensures that we can see the actual code you're asking about -- and in this case, it would have told you that the member assignment is valid before you posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine and usual to assign `struct` fields to each other. You can't assign to an array, but `struct`s provide a sort of exception to this, because an assignment of one `struct` to another results in the destination receiving a copy of the first `struct`. In the code below, you could not assign `copy_my_a.str = my_a.str;`, because these are array fields. You *could* assign `copy_my_a = my_a;` though.

Nested `struct`s are copied in the same way, so if a `struct` containing another `struct` is assigned, the entire `struct`, including the nested `struct` is copied.

If a `struct` contains an array field, that array is copied to the destination `struct`. Since this is a copy, it may be altered independently of the original array. But if a `struct` contains a pointer to some allocation (an array, dynamic allocation, etc.) it is the pointer that gets copied, not the contents of the allocation (i.e., array, etc.). This is usually called a *shallow copy* (though not a term used in the C Standard).

You have to be careful with this when assigning `structs`; if you change an array through a pointer in one `struct`, the change will be visible in all `struct`s using that pointer.

In the example below, `my_a` has an array field, and `my_b` has a `char *` field. `my_a.str` is initialized to hold a string (`"my_a"`), and `my_b.str` is initialized with a pointer to the first element of a string (`"my_b"`). Copies of each of the two `struct`s are made through assignment.

In the copy of `my_a`, `copy_my_a.str` is a copy of `my_a.str`, so the entire array has been copied to the new `struct`. Changing the original string here will not affect the copy. Similarly, in the copy of `my_b`, `copy_my_b.str` is a copy of `my_b.str`, but here it is not an array that is copied, but a pointer only. Changing the string pointed to will be visible in both `struct`s because they share the same array through a pointer.

This can trip you up if you are working with copies of such `struct`s and modify a shared string through a pointer without realizing that the string is shared, as in the final example in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct st {
    char c;
    int y;
};

struct exa {
    int x;
    struct st s;
    char str[100];
};

struct exb {
    int x;
    struct st s;
    char *str;
};

int main(void)
{
    // .str holds an array: can't assign an array to an array
    struct exa my_a = { .x = 1,
                        .s.c = 'x',
                        .s.y = 2,
                        .str = "my_a"
    };

    // .str holds a pointer to char: assign a pointer to arr[0]
    char arr[100] = "my_b";
    struct exb my_b = { .x = 1,
                        .s.c = 'x',
                        .s.y = 2,
                        .str = arr
    };

    struct exa copy_my_a = my_a;
    struct exb copy_my_b = my_b;

    puts("Nested structs are copied: ");
    printf("my_a.s.c:      %c\n", my_a.s.c);
    printf("copy_my_a.s.c: %c\n", copy_my_a.s.c);
    putchar('\n');

    puts("copy_my_a.str is a copy of my_a.str, which is an array:");
    printf("my_a.str:      %s\n", my_a.str);
    printf("copy_my_a.str: %s\n", copy_my_a.str);
    putchar('\n');

    puts("Changing the original array is not visible in the copy:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof "changed"; i++) {
        my_a.str[i] = "changed"[i];
    }

    printf("my_a.str:      %s\n", my_a.str);
    printf("copy_my_a.str: %s\n", copy_my_a.str);
    putchar('\n');

    puts("copy_my_b.str is a copy of my_b.str, which is a pointer to arr[0]:");

    printf("my_b.str:      %s\n", my_b.str);
    printf("copy_my_b.str: %s\n", copy_my_b.str);
    putchar('\n');

    puts("Changing the original array is visible in both structs:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof "changed"; i++) {
        arr[i] = "changed"[i];
    }

    printf("my_b.str:      %s\n", my_b.str);
    printf("copy_my_b.str: %s\n", copy_my_b.str);
    putchar('\n');

    puts("But changing the array through .str is also visible in both structs:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof "oops!"; i++) {
        copy_my_b.str[i] = "oops!"[i];
    }

    printf("my_b.str:      %s\n", my_b.str);
    printf("copy_my_b.str: %s\n", copy_my_b.str);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Nested structs are copied: 
my_a.s.c:      x
copy_my_a.s.c: x

copy_my_a.str is a copy of my_a.str, which is an array:
my_a.str:      my_a
copy_my_a.str: my_a

Changing the original array is not visible in the copy:
my_a.str:      changed
copy_my_a.str: my_a

copy_my_b.str is a copy of my_b.str, which is a pointer to arr[0]:
my_b.str:      my_b
copy_my_b.str: my_b

Changing the original array is visible in both structs:
my_b.str:      changed
copy_my_b.str: changed

But changing the array through .str is also visible in both structs:
my_b.str:      oops!
copy_my_b.str: oops!
```